Using fgets() function in c
I am a newbie in C. Consider my following code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char strs[5][6];
    char temporary[5]="";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        fgets(temporary,6,stdin);
        if(strlen(temporary)>5)
        temporary[strlen(temporary)-1]='\0';
        strcpy(strs[i],temporary);
    }

    printf("%s done\n",strs[0]);
    printf("%s done\n",strs[1]);
    printf("%s done\n",strs[2]);
    printf("%s done\n",strs[3]);
    printf("%s done\n",strs[4]);

    return 0;
}

The question may have probable duplicates, but I could not find one. Now, I have come across some confusions. First of all, the line temporary[strlen(temporary)-1]='\0'; erases off the final character in the string. So if the user inputs \n, then fgets() encounters the newline character [for the sake of clarity, consider that the character length has never been 5 in any of these inputs, it's always been 4]. Then, here is an output that I receive:
In case the input is: Barn
I could never go to the next line pressing Enter. Moreover, the output for all inputs being five letter is even more horrible.
Dhaka
Pabna
Tales

gives the output:
 done

 done
Pabna done

 done
Tales done

I've no idea what has happened. I just want only five characters to be taken as input. If user input is of four characters, the newline is received and stored as a character, whereas, if it is of five letters, it shall remain as it is. So, what I am missing?

if(strlen(temporary)>5) this condition will be always false as fgets(..., 6, ...) will replace the 6'th character with \0 no matter what (if the input string is longer than 5 characters). Also temporary is defined as 5 character long, meaning you will get a buffer overflow.

fgets(temporary, 6, stdin); is wrong, it should be fgets(temporary, sizeof temporary, stdin);

Please see Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input for a bullet-proof way to remove any trailing newline.

And don't be mean with your buffer sizes. There won't be any trailing newline if the buffer is too small. For user input always use a generous buffer so that you can process all the likely input and discard if it's not right. Otherwise if the user enters too much data you have the messy job of cleaning up what's still in the input buffer. So, for example use char temporary[100].

You declared char temporary[5], then you do fgets(temporary,6,stdin)  Can you see how this is a bug?  Hint:  6 is greater than 5.  That's a buffer overflow.  It's a severe bug.  Never write past the end of an array.

@TomKarzes To be fully precise: Not necessarily, if user input is short enough...

Side note: I personally (almost) always allocate buffers with sizes of powers of two (e.g. 16, 64, 1024, …).

By the way: Get used to proper indentation! This minimalistic example might yet work for you (or others), but you won't always be writing just a dozen of lines. Once your code gets more complicated you will be producing your own night mare if you don't.

@Aconcagua Right, but it's a vulnerability, similar to using gets instead of fgets.  It won't always overflow, but it can overflow.

@TomKarzes On that I fully agree ;)

@Aconcagua Any decent compiler will optimize repeated calls to strlen(). This is more of a style choice than a concern about performance. Not to mention that iterating over a small buffer is negligible.

Of course not in general. But for standard functions like strlen the compiler knows. There are many situations where it can see that nothing can modify the string between the calls.

@Aconcagua Every time I see someone make your recommendation, it's in a situation where the compiler can clearly optimize. The strict aliasing rule and the restrict qualifier provide additional assurances.

@Barmar Oh, forget about – and let him continue following the pattern even when he shouldn't.

BTW: About the buffer overflow, I believe some compilers would be able to tell you about it, if you compiled with warnings enabled. Make that your habit and don't silence warnings but understand and fix them instead.

There's too much extra work going on in your code. Pray, why are you first reading input into temporary and then copying that to another string, instead of reading the input directly into the final string?
Now about the bugs:


fgets(temporary,6,stdin);

is awry. temporary can only hold 5 characters, not 6. This is only
inviting a buffer overflow attack it. 6 should be changed to
sizeof temporary.


if(strlen(temporary)>5)

can not be true. fgets() would replace the last character (the 6th
character) will the null byte ('\0'), and the return value of strlen()
would always be less than or equal to 5, never greater than 5.


temporary[strlen(temporary)-1]='\0';

is again doing extra work. Why not cache the value of strlen() instead of
calling it again? (As Barmar mentions in the comments, the compiler would likely optimize this out). But then the calculation is buggy. What happens when an empty
string was provided as input? strlen(temporary) would return 0, and you
would be writing to out of bounds memory, and hence invoking undefined
behavior. This is better:
size_t len = strlen();

if (len > 0 && temporary[len - 1] == '\n') { 
    temporary[len-1] = 0; 
} 



Other than that, these 5 printf() calls:
printf("%s done\n",strs[0]);
printf("%s done\n",strs[1]);
printf("%s done\n",strs[2]);
printf("%s done\n",strs[3]);
printf("%s done\n",strs[4]);

can be replaced with a loop and a single printf() call:
/* See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c */
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof strs / sizeof *strs; ++i) {
    printf("%s done\n", strs[i]);
}

Note that there are other, and simpler, ways of stripping the newline from a string. See: Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input.

Uh... While you correctly fall back to sizeof(temporary) you introduce another magic number in the new for loop. Should be sizeof(strs)/sizeof(*strs) there, too – maybe explaining why the division for the case the trick is unknown.

I personally like the strchr approach better; it requires just a single check of the result – or the strcspn variant (see link in comments to question).

@Aconcagua 1. Yes, that was just me being indolent. 2. That's the version I prefer too, unless I require the length as well. I've edited the answer to include a link to other approaches.

Does not fgets(temporary,6,stdin); capture 5 characters from the input stream? So why cannot I keep temporary a string of 5 characters and make it temporary[5];?Or I am being  confused....?

As an addendum to Harith’s answer, here is a corrected version of your code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef ARRAY_SIZE
    #define ARRAY_SIZE(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof((array)[0]))
#endif

int main()
{
    char strs[5][6];

    for(int i=0;  i<ARRAY_SIZE(strs);  i++)
    {
        if (!fgets(strs[i],sizeof(strs[i]),stdin)) return 1;
        strs[i][strcspn(strs[i],"\n\r")]='\0';
    }

    for (int i=0;  i<ARRAY_SIZE(strs);  i++
    {
        printf("%s done\n",strs[i]);
    }
}

This has the following advantages:

You can change the size of both the strs array and of the string elements of that array in the one spot without having to find magic numbers elsewhere in your code.

It uses loops to make repetitive tasks simpler.

It is shorter and easier to read.


It has the following disadvantages:

Five characters is not a lot of space for a user input. Are you sure that the user will press Enter before hitting that 6-character string limit?

If the user does exceed the string limit, unread characters in the input have not been acknowledged. This will result in unexpected values for the next input.


Remember, whenever asked for input, the user (which includes you!) will always type his or her answer and then press Enter. Each time the Enter key is pressed, that should be the end of that input!
It may be erroneous, but a requested input should not be broken by the previous input.
How you handle this is up to you. You could:

Do as above and pretend it never happens.
Crash and burn: ask the user to try running the program correctly and quit.
Ignore everything extra on the line.

For those last two you need a little more code:
        fgets(strs[i],sizeof(strs[i]),stdin);
        char*p = strpbrk(strs[i],"\r\n");
        if (!p) COMPLAIN_HERE;
        *p='\0';

In place of ‘COMPLAIN_HERE’ invoke one of the options listed above.
BTW, the strpbrk() version was shown for completeness. If you are using the standard input stream (as you are here), then strchr() suffices: CR,LF input sequences are automatically transformed so that all you get is an '\n'.

Interestingly enough I didn't find a question about ignoring surplus input in C; seems pretty simple, though: for(int c = getChar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getChar()); ;)

@Aconcagua Yes, but I should have also been explicit that ignoring any input is usually an indication of design failure. If the input is too large then that is an error which should be reported to the user. Crash and burn is usually the correct option.

@Aconcagua There are numerous. See for instance: How to clear stdin before getting new input?.

You should check that fgets() does not report EOF (by returning NULL) before trying to use the result.

Yoinks! Stoopid mistake. (Fixed)

int main()
{
    char strs[5][6];
    char temporary[5]="";

temporary has only space for 5 characters (and to use fgets it only allows you to read 4 characters, if you specify the space as 5, but
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        fgets(temporary,6,stdin);

you specify temporary has been reserved 6 characters, and this will make fgets to think (erroneusly) that it can write on 6 character positions.  This  is a serious error, comonly known as buffer overflow and results in undefined behaviour, You should say fgets the exact amount of characters available in the the buffer (including any required space for the string terminator)
        if(strlen(temporary)>5)
        temporary[strlen(temporary)-1]='\0';

This step is never necessary, as fgets always stops before having to write a non-null character into the buffer, and the returned string will always be properly terminated.
        strcpy(strs[i],temporary);
    }

So your code (despite all the recomendations you have received in the other answers) should have been (I'll respect your decision of using the unneeded temporary variable, etc.):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N_STRINGS      5
#define STR_LEN        6

int main()
{
    char strs[N_STRINGS][STR_LEN];
    char temporary[STR_LEN]; /* no initializer needed, as you are assigning a 
                              * a value in fgets() call */
    for(int i = 0; i < N_STRINGS; i++) /* spaces are cheap */
    {
        fgets(temporary, STR_LEN, stdin);
        strcpy(strs[i], temporary);
    }

    /* better use a loop, so if you change N_STRINGS, you will
     * not be required to add extra printf() calls */
    for (int i = 0; i < N_STRINGS; i++) {
        printf("%s done\n", strs[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}


declare a character,
char n;
after each scan add,
while((n=getchar())!='\n');
it "eats" any extra characters and you have a clean buffer for the next scan
Lifesaver!

Inifinte loop if EOF

You need to use int n; while ((n = getchar()) != EOF && n != '\n') ; spread over 3 lines (the semicolon would be on a line on its own, not at the end of the loop line) — the return type of getchar() is int, not char, and you need to handle EOF as well as newline.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
